# Resolving: Error when checking input: expected dense_125_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (192, 192, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to get my first net running. The following error occures:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_125_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (192, 192, 1)

```py
# ... images 300 px width/height
def preprocess_image(image):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=1)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [192, 192])
    image /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range
    return image

# creating the dataset
def prepare_data_train(path, label_from_filename, show=False):
    images = []
    labels = []

    for file in glob.glob(path + '*.jpg'):
        label = label_from_filename(file)
        if label != False:
            images.append(file)
            labels.append(label)

    path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images)
    image_ds = path_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

    label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.cast(labels, tf.int32))
    image_label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((image_ds, label_ds))

    # shuffling, batch size
    BATCH_SIZE = 20
    image_count = len(images)
    # Setting a shuffle buffer size as large as the dataset ensures that the data is
    # completely shuffled.
    ds = image_label_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=image_count)
    ds = ds.repeat()
    ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    # `prefetch` lets the dataset fetch batches, in the background while the model is training.
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

    keras_ds = ds.map(change_range)
    image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(keras_ds))

    return image_label_ds

# running ...
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(192,)))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_ds = prepare_data_train(path_train, label_from_filename, False)
validation_ds = prepare_data_test(path_test, label_from_filename, False)

# error when fitting
history = model.fit(train_ds,
                    batch_size=20,
                    epochs=10,
                    verbose=2,
                    validation_steps=2,
                    steps_per_epoch=2,
                    validation_data=validation_ds)
```

How to resolve it? Is reshaping needed, how?

Based on the images the net should predict 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this line in your code:

```
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(192,)))
```

Namely, the shape of your input is 3 dimensional `[width, height, channels]` or `[192, 192, 1]`. So, if you really want to have that dense layer at the start, change the model definition to:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=[192, 192, 1]))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

The line `model.add(Flatten(input_shape=[192, 192, 1]))` will flatten your input to be a single vector for each element in the batch. Then, you can proceed as you want.

Comment: Thank you. :-) Now the error is `Error when checking input: expected dense_129_input to have shape (192, 192) but got array with shape (192, 1)`. I've tried multiple values for input_shape. Always the expected and input shape changes.

Comment: I'm struggling to get it working - not matter if that layer combination makes sense. Still getting: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_2_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (192, 192, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when You put wrong train data to model.fit attribute. Check Your train_ds by `print(train_ds)` before passing it to model.fit. It should return something like:

```
<SkipDataset shapes: ((192, 192, 1), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>
```